# Recursive string reverse syntax error

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class Problems {
String a = "Tester";
public static String reverse(String s) 
{ 
    int m = s.length(); 

    if(m<=1) 
    {
        return s; 
    }
    else
    {
        m=m/2; 
        String r1=reverse(s.substring(0,m)); 
        String r2=reverse(s.substring(m)); 
        return (r2+r1); 
    }
} 


reverse(a);
System.out.println(a);
```

}

I currently have this for a recursive string program, but I am getting an insert "}" to complete body. It's probably something easy, but I'm not sure why my program isn't compiling. Are there any other errors in my program? I really appreciate your help, I hope I am able to get this working! Thanks guys

Comment: I'd wager that you need to add `}` to close off one of your loops or functions or classes. This is why indenting is so important. Also, you have two statements outside of any method, which means that it won't compile

Comment: Please use a good IDE. It would detect this type of errors pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a main(assuming intention is to run it)

Here is somewhat changed program..

```
public class Problems {

    public  static String reverse(String s) {
        int m = s.length();

        if (m <= 1) {
            return s;
        } else {
            m = m / 2;
            String r1 = reverse(s.substring(0, m));
            String r2 = reverse(s.substring(m));
            return (r2 + r1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "Tester";
        String result=reverse(a);

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could have left the method reverse() as a static and skip the object instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

These lines

```
reverse(a);
System.out.println(a);
```

Are outside your method. That is not valid in Java. Only declarations may occur outside of methods (at the class level). Fix this by moving the `}` which is directly above them to the line directly below them.

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
reverse(a);
System.out.println(a);
```

should either be in a static method, or a constructor/initializer.
Apart from that, why don't you simply use `new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString()`?